# How to prevent the page loads by linkbutton?

Tags: asp.net

I m making a quiz game like KBC in ASP.NET (C#). I have used textbox as question. And four radiobuttons as four options. Radiobuttons are placed in a groupbox. I have given 3 linkbuttons for ‘Back’, ‘Next’, ‘Submit’.

The questions are generated randomly via the database. Code Sample:

```
page_load(…) {
  // database connectivity
  RandomFunction();
}

RandomFunction() {
  //random numbers generated
  Question();
}

Question() {
  //displays question on textbox & options on radiobuttons
}
```

Now my question is how can the ‘Next’ or ‘Back’ linbuttons can show the next or exactly the previous question respectively? Since as soon as they get clicked then the whole page is loaded which i don’t want to happen. (i have already used ‘isPostback’ in ‘RandomFunction()’ so as to prevent the change in indexing of the questions in each postbacks. )

Comment: The "Next" and "Back" buttons should have on their Click events Response.Redirect("url")

Comment: What is exactly your problem? The page refreshing?

Comment: Are you using clientside javascript to show the different questions? If not (using server side) then you need a reload/postback when you hit next/back?

Comment: @Gogutz.. I cant do that.. I have only one page to show the textbox & radiobuttons.. I cannot redirect to some else page..

Comment: @adripanico .. My problem is that when the Next or Back buttons get clicked, the whole page gets refreshed and the code inside the click event of those linkbuttons does not get executed..

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck.. I m using server side code.. And i have tried postbacks and even Ajax too.. but still not able to execute the code inside the Linkbuttons' Click event.. Instead the whole page gets refreshed.

Comment: You need to use an UpdatePanel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: got it... thank u all of u guys.. really appreciate u all